# multiprocessing python selenium dataframe

Tags: python, multithreading, dataframe, selenium, python-multiprocessing

I've been trying to use ways to speed up web automation executions with Selenium for a long time.
After a lot of study, mistakes, I think I'm getting close to the intended result. But I need your help lol.
I'm using threads to handle various instances of chromedriver.
I need each instance to search for an element on google. My code is running a json file and searching for the term. It works as I wish. This is the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
import json
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def test_instance(data):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    chrome.maximize_window()
    chrome.get("https://www.google.com/")


    username_field = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@title="Pesquisar"]')
    username_field.send_keys(data['username'])
    time.sleep(10)





f = open('test.json', )
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
process_count = 2  # number of tests to run (each test open a separate browser)
thread_list = []

# Start test
for i in range(process_count):
    t = threading.Thread(name=f'Test {i}', target=test_instance, args=[data[i]])
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.name + ' started')
    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print('Test completed')
```

But instead of using a json file as a database, I wanted to use an excel file. But I'm not getting each browser to go through the lines without repeating the same search.

My json file is this one:

```
[
    {
        "username": "test1"
        
    },

    {
        "username": "test2"
       
    }
]
```

How can I perform the same automation by reading the excel file?

Thank you for your valuable time and your sincere help.

To try to find out with pandas I made the following modification. But I don't know how to pass the value of the lines as an argument to the search

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def test_instance(valor):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    chrome.maximize_window()
    chrome.get("https://www.google.com/")
    username_field = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@title="Pesquisar"]')
    username_field.send_keys(valor)
    time.sleep(5)




wb = load_workbook(filename = 'test.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb.active
linha = sheet_ranges['A']
for celula in linha:
    valor = celula.value

process_count = 2  # number of tests to run (each test open a separate browser)
thread_list = []

# Start test
for i in range(process_count):
    t = threading.Thread(name=f'Test {i}', target=test_instance, args= valor)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.name + ' started')
    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print('Test completed')
```

Comment: what did you try to do? Where is code which reads Excel? Do you know modules to read excel? [Python Resources for working with Excel - Working with Excel Files in Python](https://www.python-excel.org/). You could even use `pandas` to read it and iterate rows in `DataFrame`. After reading data to python rest code can be similar.

Comment: @furas I modified the question by introducing the attempt to integer with openpyxl.

Comment: standard rule: if you use `for`-loop then you have to use `list` to keep all values - `all_valors = []` and `for celula in linha: all_valors.append( celula.value )` and later you can use `args= all_values[i]`

Comment: @furas Thanks for your help so far. Could you help me even more? I have the following error: `TypeError: test_instance() takes 1 positional argument but 25 were given`

Comment: maybe first use `print(...)`, `print(len(...))`, `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables. Maybe it gets full row from excel and you should get only one value from row. It may need to use `[0]` in some place.